# Android Collapsing Toolbar not working with RecyclerView

Tags: android, xml, kotlin

I tried implementing a collapsing toolbar, but it is not working for some reason. The toolbar is visible, but not collapsing when recycler is scrolled.

I based it on [this example](https://material.io/develop/android/components/collapsing-toolbar-layout/)

Here is my layout:

```
<androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:background="@color/colorBackground"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">

<androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
    android:id="@+id/recyclerView"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:clipToPadding="false"
    android:overScrollMode="never"
    android:paddingBottom="8dp"
    android:scrollbars="vertical"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
    app:layoutManager="androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager"
    tools:listitem="@layout/row_youtube_video" />

<com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="@dimen/tall_toolbar_height">

    <com.google.android.material.appbar.CollapsingToolbarLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:contentScrim="?attr/colorPrimary"
        app:expandedTitleGravity="top"
        app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed|snap">

        <androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            app:layout_collapseMode="pin"/>

    </com.google.android.material.appbar.CollapsingToolbarLayout>

</com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

SOLVED:

the problem was with `app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed|snap"`

for my use-case, I just needed `app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways"`